# Spring Boot: Custom PageImpl not working with latest Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Upgrading Jackson in a Spring Boot application was not without difficulties and problems.
Running 2.1.11.RELEASE, and Java 8

I upgraded Jackson from 2.9.10 to 2.15.2.

```
<!-- Jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now my Client failed to work with my `CustomPage extends PageImpl`.
I no longer got any values for `size`, `page`, `total`, `hasNext()` or `next()`.
All page variables was either zero or false.

My Custom PageImpl:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"pageable", "sort"})
public class CustomDtoPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {

    private int number;
    private int size;
    private int totalPages;
    private int numberOfElements;
    private long totalElements;
    private boolean previousPage;
    private boolean first;
    private boolean nextPage;
    private boolean last;
    private Sort sort;
    private CustomDtoPageable pageable;

    public CustomDtoPage(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
    }

    public CustomDtoPage(List<T> content) {
        super(content);
    }

    public CustomDtoPage() {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public PageImpl<T> pageImpl() {
        return new PageImpl<>(getContent(), PageRequest.of(getNumber(), getSize(), getSort()), getTotalElements());
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomDtoPageable extends PageRequest {

    public CustomDtoPageable() {
        super(1, 1);
    }
    
}
```

I tried updating it similar to the CustomPageImpl from the following guide, but same problem with it.
https://www.baeldung.com/resttemplate-page-entity-response

My new Custom PageImpl according to the example in the article:

```
public class CustomDtoPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public CustomDtoPage(@JsonProperty("content") List<T> content,
                   @JsonProperty("number") int number,
                   @JsonProperty("size") int size,
                   @JsonProperty("totalElements") Long totalElements,
                   @JsonProperty("pageable") JsonNode pageable,
                   @JsonProperty("last") boolean last,
                   @JsonProperty("totalPages") int totalPages,
                   @JsonProperty("sort") JsonNode sort,
                   @JsonProperty("numberOfElements") int numberOfElements) {
        super(content, PageRequest.of(number, size), totalElements);
    }

    public CustomDtoPage(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
    }

    public CustomDtoPage(List<T> content) {
        super(content);
    }

    public CustomDtoPage() {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
    }

}
```

This will fail because there are no value for `size` and `totalElements`.\

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page size must not be less than one!

The page and size was available in the pageable JsonNode, so I change the constructor to this
`super(content, PageRequest.of(pageable.get("page").asInt(), pageable.get("size").asInt()), 10);`
This does not work. I only get one page, because it does not have any next.

`super(content, PageRequest.of(pageable.get("page").asInt(), 1), 10);`
This does work. However since total is hardcoded to 10 it stops at page 9, even though totalPages is way higher (and unknown to me).

I printed out the values I got when deserializing the PageImpl.
With my old CustomDtoPage

```
pageable {"class":"org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest","page":"0","size":"500","sort":{"orders":{"class":"java.util.Arrays$ArrayList","a":{"class":"org.springframework.data.domain.Sort$Order-array"}}}}
number 0
size 0
totalPages 0
totalElements 0
numberOfElements 0
first false
last false
```

With the Updated CustomDtoPage that uses JsonCreator constructor, and JsonProperty for parameters

```
pageable null
number 0
size 0
totalPages 0
totalElements 0
numberOfElements 0
first false
last false
hasNext false
```

These are the values I expect to get, and are getting when running with the older version of Jackson

```
number 0
size 500
totalPages 94
totalElements 46818
numberOfElements 500
first true
last false
hasNext true
```

Is there any way I can get this back to work as it did with the older version of Jackson?

I have tried several suggestions I have found online, and on Stackoverflow, none worked.

This is the Page structure I get from calling the endpoint using the Postman application.

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "myContentHere": ""
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "unsorted": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "empty": true
        },
        "pageSize": 500,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "last": false,
    "totalElements": 46818,
    "totalPages": 94,
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 500,
    "sort": {
        "unsorted": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "empty": true
    },
    "size": 500,
    "number": 0,
    "empty": false
}
```

Upgrading the client to Spring Boot 2.2.2, while still using Jackson 1.15.2 did not solve my problems.
I even tried upgrading Spring Boot to 2.7.12.

Edit: I started to investigate the response my client gets, to see if the values are actually there.
This is the response I get when running with Jackson 2.14.2 or 2.15.2

```
<org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl>
<content>
</content>
<pageable class="org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest">
  <page>0</page><size>500</size>
  <sort>
    <orders class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList"><a class="org.springframework.data.domain.Sort$Order-array"/></orders>
  </sort>
</pageable>
<total>46818</total>
</org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl>
```

Why I get XML and not JSON I am not sure about (but that is beside the point)
As you can see it only has a total value.
So all the others are thus not present (number, size, totalElements, etc.).

Running with Jackson 2.9.10 instead

```
  "content":[{}],
  "pageable
    "sort": {
        "unsorted":true,"sorted":false,"empty":true
    },
    "pageSize":500,
    "pageNumber":0,
    "offset":0,
    "unpaged":false,
    "paged":true
  },
  "last":false,
  "totalElements":46818,
  "totalPages":94,
  "first":true,
  "numberOfElements":500,
  "sort": {
    "unsorted":true,
    "sorted":false,
    "empty":true
  },
  "size":500,
  "number":0,
  "empty":false
```

There all values are present in the JSON.

Why are they not present when I use the newer version of Jackson?

Comment: afaik the default for enums and Jackson is to use the String representation and not the ordinal value. Hence there must be something in your configuration that has changed that.

Comment: String Enum name is default yes. However I am using a custom code to represent the JSON value for my Enum. And it only works with Jackson 2.14+.
I have not used Enum directly in my DTO classes before, just the Integer value. Now when I updated my DTOs to use the Enum I got this problem.
This can be changed by defining which variable should be used for serialization with @JsonValue annortation.

Comment: Which is the problem you described that it didn't use the name of the enum but the ordinal value? So which is is? Or else describe your problem in more detail (with examples what you initially had and what didn't work).I also don't get your statement about that there is no `size` and `totalElements` as the JSON clearly states it does. Is there a special reason not the use the default `PageImpl`? As it seems to just map the result as well. If the only problem was an enum mapping I don't really get it?

Comment: 1. I upgraded to Jackson 2.15 because of a problem with using Enum's in my DTOs (which I previously used Integer for the Enum).

2. My Custom PageImpl no longer works as a result of newer Jackson.

3. The Values in my Custom PageImpl was not set. next was always false, size, totalElemets, totalPages, etc. was all zero (0).

The JSON i get from Postman clearly states that it has size, page, totalElements, totalPages, etc, but even though I am binding those in my Custom PageImp these values are null/zero.

Comment: I tried to explain the reason why I upgraded to new Jackson, but the enum problem is not the problem I am trying to solve. Perhaps I should remove it from the Question.

Comment: I find your question confusing and the comments don't really help clarifying things. There is an enum problem, but there isn't. You upgraded because of enums, but according to you it wasn't the reason. I'm a bit lost on what is going on. Please provide a reproducable sample that shows the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is not an Enum problem. I have removed all mention on Enums now. This is a problem of upgrading to newer version of Jackson. The question has been updated.

Comment: You said you followd the guide as mentioned in the link, ou didn't. You decided to add properties and use lombok to add getters/setters for the properties. But you are never setting them. DItch all those attributes and just call the super constructor. As you are using Spring Boot you shouldn't be messing around with Jackson dependencies yourself (in general). I still don't get why you upgraded in the first place (as mentioned before), and please provide sample code that we can run, as it keeps getting more vague.

Comment: I tried with changing my CustomDtoPage according to the Example in the link. I provided the excact same constructor with the JsonCreator annotation. Thus also removed the parameters I had, and Lombok. I have updated the Question how I changed my custom PageImpl.
I am able to get this new custom PageImp working only with the older Jackson that is provided with Spring Boot 2.1.11 I am using, but not any newer version of Jackson.

Comment: This is still not a reproducable sample, just snippets. Please provide a sample that runs with the old versions and not with the newer version. Is it the endpoint? Is it the binding with the resttemplate that isn't working? Add the configuration etc.